# export SQL data to Excel in Android Studio

Tags: android, sql, excel

I have a simple DB with several tables.
I would like to export the DB to excel, where each tab has a different table's data.
I also want it to be readable data in a way that where I use id's I will replace it with the description from another table

I could export the data into CSV file as follow (found this code in another answer).

I could also export the **entire** DB by using SQLiteToExcel, but didn't find a way to manipulate the data.

so my (long) question is how to keep using the CSV and than make an excel tab out of it, or use entirely the SQLiteToExcel

```
 private class ExportDatabaseCSVTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Exporting database...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(final String... args) {

            File file = getFileExcel();
            try {


                file.createNewFile();
                CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));

                //data

                List<RelavantDataRows> data = dbHelper.getRelavantDataRows(false);
                String[] ColumnName = RelavantDataRows.getColumnsNamesAsStringArr();
                csvWrite.writeNext(ColumnName);
                if (data != null) {
                    for (RelavantDataRows row :
                            data) {
                        String[] data_row = row.getDataAsStringArr();
                        csvWrite.writeNext(data_row);
                    }
                }
                csvWrite.close();
                return "";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "";
            }
        }
```

using SQLiteToExcel :

```
  SQLiteToExcel sqliteToExcel = new SQLiteToExcel(MainActivity.this, DATABASE_NAME);
 sqliteToExcel.exportAllTables("table1.xls", new SQLiteToExcel.ExportListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(String filePath) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Excel File  created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so, it seems that I didn't read the manual :)
looking at the readme of the SQLiteToExcel package, they've added more functionality - exactly what I needed:
how to exclude columns
how to pretty names (both columns and values)

after reading their examples I was able to export each table in a separate tab, and remove some columns (like ids) and replace the names of columns, and values of the reference table with the actual value. All is very explanatory.

here is the github:
[SQLite2XL](https://github.com/androidmads/SQLite2XL/blob/master/README.md)

good luck!